# Unable to resolve dependency tree, found version is same as peer

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

Node v17.8.0 (npm v8.5.5)

Trying to install and I'm getting this error. The found version appears to satisfy the required peer version but still errors. As I understand it, the ^carat should allow minor version increases. Can anyone explain this?

```
Found: react-native@0.64.3

Peer: react-native@^0.60.0
```

```
npm ERR! While resolving: myApp@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react-native@0.64.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   react-native@"^0.64.0" from myApp@1.0.0
npm ERR!   packages/app/myApp
npm ERR!     myApp@1.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/myApp
npm ERR!       workspace packages/app/myApp from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native@"^0.60.0" from react-native-bottomsheet@2.5.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-bottomsheet
npm ERR!   react-native-bottomsheet@"^2.2.0" from myApp@1.0.0
npm ERR!   packages/app/myApp
npm ERR!     myApp@1.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/myApp
npm ERR!       workspace packages/app/myApp from the root project
```

EDIT: I know I can use `--legacy-peer-deps` but I want to understand why it is a problem in the first place.

Comment: 0.x.y versions are different, 0.64.3 is **not** compatible with ^0.60.0

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought that was the entire point of the carat, to make all following 0.x.y versions compatible 

Comment: Again major version 0 is different, ~ and ^ are effectively the same. Read https://semver.org/ or try it out on https://semver.npmjs.com/.

Comment: I understand now, "caret behavior is different for 0.x versions, for which it will only match patch versions." thanks for the link and info 

Comment: @jonrsharpe you should add comments as an answer so this question can be updated as answered.